# I'm trying to root my HTC Desire 510, and can't figure out how exactly I'm supposed to flash over the recovery ROM

Tags: android, disk-image

I'm following [this tutorial](https://support.digitalendpoint.com/hc/en-us/articles/204812787-How-to-root-the-HTC-Desire-510) on rooting the HTC Desire 510, and I've managed to unlock the bootloader. However, I'm stuck on step 3, where it says to download the image file and extract it, after which I should have something called `recovery.img`. Now, I tried extracting the image downloaded using 7zip, but that only got me gibberish files without extensions. How exactly am I supposed to proceed?

Comment: Define "gibberish."  Turn off "hide extensions."  Nobody can help you if you don't provide enough information.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I have extensions turned on by default, this just had no extension. As for "gibberish", what I mean was that there was no definable pattern or meaning behind the name of the file, nor was the file clear when I tried giving it various extensions.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  This is the file that I downloaded from step 3: TWRP_2.8.1.0_A11.img, nothing to extract since its an img file.  You might just need to rename that to recovery.img and try to proceed from there.

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get home, thank you.